# how to draw repeating tasks in Gantt chart using mermaid

Tags: markdown, gantt-chart, mermaid

I was using Typora to draw Gantt chart with mermaid and couldn't find a way to draw repeating tasks. The code as follows:

```
gantt
dateFormat ss
axisFormat %S
    section Round Robin scheduling
    p1: a, 00, 01
    p2: a, 01, 02
    p3: a, 02, 03
    p4: a, 03, 04
    p5: a, 04, 05
    p1: a, 05, 06
```

[picture of that gantt chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Zg6.png)
it turns out to be that the repeating tasks of p1 are not in the same line. The latter p1 is recognized as another task. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to get *just* `p1` on the same line both times, but you can use the [compact display mode](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/gantt.html#output-in-compact-mode) to collapse tasks onto the same line when they fit:

```html
<script type="module">
  import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
  mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
</script>

<pre class="mermaid">
---
displayMode: compact
---

%% The preceding YAML block turns on compact mode

gantt
dateFormat ss
axisFormat %S
    section Round Robin scheduling
    p1: a, 00, 01
    p2: a, 01, 02
    p3: a, 02, 03
    p4: a, 03, 04
    p5: a, 04, 05
    p1: a, 05, 06
</pre>
```